# Drupal 8 - photos uploaded using iOS devices are rotated

Tags: ios, iphone, image-uploading, drupal-8, image-rotation

When using iOS devices such as the iPhone  (and possibly other devices; not Android devices however), photos taken and uploaded in drupal 8 are rotated to a 90 degree angle.

For example, images taken and uploaded vertical are posted horizontal.
Images taken and uploaded horizontal are posted upside down.

Any help would be appreciated

Many thanks

------------------EDIT---------------

I'm currently using Drupal 8's code, so the code is in its original state.
Is there a way to not change the code and download a module or something which can correct the problem?

Below is an example of how images are automatically rotated from the uploaded/original image and posted image...

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOIrr.jpg)

Comment: If you want someone to show you where your code is wrong, you need to show your code. Otherwise the answer is rotate your image 90 or -90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I have edited my original post. 
Please take a look, and let me know if you need further information.

Comment: In order to get help, you need to show us where you are stuck. If you haven't written any code, write some, get an error message show us the message and the code that caused it. Then we can help.

Comment: I have resolved this issue, turned out it was to do with the server not being able to read EXIF information when images are taken and uploaded using iPhone.

I installed this and the problem was fixed...

https://www.drupal.org/project/exif_orientation

Comment: Excellent. Congrats.